# Why can't $\frac{d}{d \theta}$ be considered as a globally defined vector field on $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Why can't $\frac{d}{d \theta}$ be considered as a globally defined vector field on $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifoolds, page 176 Second edition, Example 8.4:

Let $\theta$ be any angle coordinate on a proper open subset $U \subset S^1$ and let $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ denote the corresponding vector field. Because 
any other angle coordinate $\gamma$ differs from $\theta$ by an additive constant in a neighborhood of each point, the transformation law for coordinate vector fields shows that $\frac{d}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{d\gamma}$ on their common domain. For this reason, there is a globally defined vector field on $S^1$ whose coordinate representation is $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ with respect to any angle coordinates. It is a smooth vector field because its component function is constant in any such chart. We denote this global vector field by $\frac{d}{d\theta}$, ***even though, strictly speaking, it cannot be considered as a coordinate vector field on the entire circle at once***

Can one of you genius's comment on the part I put in bold? Why can't $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ be considered as a coordinate vector field on the entire circle at once?

Comment: I think the main word here is **coordinate**. It cannot be considered as a coordinate vectore field on the entire circle at once, but it is a global vector field, i.e. a vector field on the entire circle at once.The vector field $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ is the vector field of the coordinate $\theta$, but theta is not global. However there is some vector field (which we again denote with $\frac{d}{d\theta}$) which is global, and equal to the vector field of $\theta$ where $\theta$ is defined, but that vector field is not a vector field of a single coordinate globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ is only defined on $U$, the coordinate chart. Since there is no global coordinate chart for $S^1$, you can’t build a vector field at every point pulling back a single tangent vector from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hello. It has been noticed that over the past hours you have made a considerable number of edits changing "Hawaiian" to "infinite" (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3032818/revisions). These are absolutely unnecessary as 1) the common term for this is the Hawaiian earring, and 2) by changing all such instances, users familiar with this term only will not be able to search for the questions you've edited. Please refrain from superfluous edits of posts.